# How to implement initialization finalizers in C++?

Tags: c++, oop

I want to implement initialization finalizer in base class. The simplest way is to provide method with finalization procedure. Unfortunately it force to remember to call it always at the end of the most-derived constructor - pretty bad for clients. I thought I can use RAII in base class to achieve ideal effect, and wrote such code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Base
{
    Base()
    {
        struct Finishializer
        {
            ~Finishializer()
            {
                cout << "Base::~Finishializer" << endl;
            }
        } finishializer;
        cout << "Base::Base()" << endl;
    }

    ~Base()
    {
        cout << "Base::~Base()" << endl;
    }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    Derived()
    {
        cout << "Derived::Derived()" << endl;
    }

    ~Derived()
    {
        cout << "Derived::~Derived()" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived();
}
```

Then I realized there is opposite order of callstack evaluation for constructors.
My "Finishializer pattern" requires to call base constructor firstly, and call derived constructor at the end of base constructor (as next stackframe).

Unfortunately, C++ (VS2015 in my case) works other way:
It calls derived constructor, but as first instruction it calls base constructor (as next stackframe).

It leads to following output:

```
Base::Base()
Base::~Finishializer
Derived::Derived()
Derived::~Derived()
Base::~Base()
```

instead of my dreamed one:

```
Base::Base()
Derived::Derived()
Base::~Finishializer
Derived::~Derived()
Base::~Base()
```

Is there some good reason to evaluate stack as it is, or maybe it can be altered as I proposed to let to implement "finishializers"? Do you know some alternative pattern to do such stuff with current C++ implementations?

Comment: what about using a factory pattern?

Comment: A good start may be to move the structure *out* of the constructor and let `finishializer` be a standard member variable.

Comment: Also, what is wrong with putting the "finishializer" code in the `Base` destructor? It kind of *is* the purpose of the destructor. Can you please elaborate on the use-case for this? What is the problem this solution is supposed to solve?

Comment: The two main general approaches are (1) factory functions, which can be templatized, and (2) a requirement of a special most derived class, that is a template.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Nope, it has to be called at the end of construction phase, not destruction.

Comment: Then your "wanted" output is *wrong*. And you *still* need to elaborate on what problem this is supposed to solve. [Please read about the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), and think about how it relates to your question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Right, fixed.

Comment: This really sounds like a design flaw.  You should not need a `finalizer` with constructors and destructors.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I don't see relation.

Comment: @NathanOliver: What is wrong with it? I know the last step of initialization procedure at base class level, but I don't have the state, which is provided in derived class construction.

Comment: This question is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) because you tell us you want a specific solution, but you don't say what problem it's supposed to solve. If we know what the problem is then it's easier to understand what you're doing and most importantly *why* you need it. And it might even be possible that someone knows of a *better* solution.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I think provided abstract should be enough as it describes quite standard problem which is usually solved by factory pattern. The problem is factory has its limitations, and constructors stack evaluation from base to derived + RAII would be ideal solution. If you need my particular, current problem then ok: I have base class GameElement which aggregate container with all rigid bodies. In derived classes at constructor level I add specific rigid bodies, but then I need to perform some standard operations for each of body. That's why I need such postinitializer.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way to do what you want to do using something in the base class. The only thing that I have found to work is to add code in the constructor of the most derived class. In your case,

```
Derived::Derived()
{
    cout << "Derived::Derived()" << endl;
    Finishializer();
}
```

That is a maintenance headache as soon as you decide to derive from `Derived` and want to exercise the code for `Finishializer();` in the newly derived class. Once again, I haven't come across a design/implementation pattern that works without explicitly adding code in the most derived class.

Comment: This is how I handle it at the moment (but by calling base method), but it force to remember about special call in each most-derived constructor.

Comment: @Piotrek, let's hope some clever programmer has found a technique that works like you want it to. If not, you'll just have to live with the limitations of the language.

Comment: I just wonder why callstack isn't evaluated as I thought during construction. Prehaps there is some good reason, but I can't find it out. Original problem is not the first one where such "finishializer" would be very convinient.

Comment: @Piotrek, that's how the language is defined. Also, it make sense that base constructors be called first before the body of the derived class constructor is called. That way, the derived class constructor has access to properly initialized members of the base class.

Comment: The problem is derived constructor is called first, and it calls base constructor at the beginning. This is why I can't use RAII for this problem.

Comment: @Piotrek, Yes, I understand that that's a problem for you. What I am telling you is that I haven't come across a solution that will do what you want to.

Answer (score 1):

The first approach below, using a factory function, is bit dirty but I think it does what you want.

Another more idiot-proof way is to require a special final class derivation for the concrete, usable classes. E.g. this approach is used, but without enforcement, in Microsoft's ATL library. But let's first do the factory:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>       // std::unique_ptr    
#include <type_traits>  // std::is_base_of
#include <utility>      // std::(forward)
using namespace std;

void say( char const* const s ) { cout << s << "\n"; }

#define STATIC_ASSERT( e ) static_assert( e, "`" #e "`  <-- must hold." )

template< class Base, class Derived >
using Is_base_and_derived = is_base_of<Base, Derived>;      // (sic!).

class Base
{
friend class Base_factory;
private:
    void finalize_construction() { say( "Finalizing construction." ); }

protected:
    virtual ~Base() { say( "Base::<destroy>" ); }
    Base() { say( "Base::<init>" ); }
};

class Derived:
    public Base
{
friend class Base_factory;
protected:
    ~Derived() override { say( "Derived::<destroy>" ); }
    Derived() { say( "Derived::<init>" ); }
};

class Base_factory
{
private:
    static void destroy( Base const* const p )
    { delete p; }

public:
    template< class Class >
    using Ptr_ = unique_ptr<Class, void(*)(Base const*)>;

    template< class Class, class... Args >
    static auto make_a( Args&&... args )
        -> Ptr_<Class>
    {
        STATIC_ASSERT(( Is_base_and_derived<Base, Class>::value ));
        auto result = Ptr_<Class>{
            new Class{ forward<Args>( args )... }, &destroy
            };
        result->finalize_construction();
        return result;
    }
};

auto main()
    -> int
{
    (void) Base_factory::make_a<Derived>();
}
```

The forced most derived class approach avoids the dynamic allocation in the code above, and it avoids reliance on client code conformance:

```
#include <assert.h>     // assert    
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>       // std::unique_ptr    
#include <type_traits>  // std::is_base_of
#include <utility>      // std::(forward)
using namespace std;

void say( char const* const s ) { cout << s << "\n"; }

#define STATIC_ASSERT( e ) static_assert( e, "`" #e "`  <-- must hold." )


//------------------------------------------- Machinery:

class With_enforced_most_derived;

template< class Some_class, class The_virtual_top = With_enforced_most_derived>
class Construction_finalizer_ final
    : public Some_class
    , public virtual The_virtual_top
{
public:
    template< class... Args >
    Construction_finalizer_( Args&&... args )
        : The_virtual_top{ typename The_virtual_top::Key{} }
        , Some_class{ forward<Args>( args )... }
    { say( "Finalizing construction." ); }
};

class With_enforced_most_derived
{
template< class, class > friend class Construction_finalizer_;
private:
    enum Key{};

public:
    With_enforced_most_derived()    // Needed for intermediate classes.
    { assert( "Most derived class must be `Construction_finalizer_`" && 0 ); }

    With_enforced_most_derived( Key )
    {}
};

//------------------------------------------- Example usage:

class Base
    : public virtual With_enforced_most_derived
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() { say( "Base::<destroy>" ); }
    Base() { say( "Base::<init>" ); }
};

class Derived:
    public Base
{
public:
    ~Derived() override { say( "Derived::<destroy>" ); }
    Derived() { say( "Derived::<init>" ); }
};


auto main()
    -> int
{
#ifdef CRASH_BABY_CRASH
    (void) Derived{};
#endif
    (void) Construction_finalizer_<Derived>{};
}
```

Comment: This is one of the way to worked it around. The problem is clent still has to have some special knowledge - in this case it is friend in derived classes and nonstandard way to create new objects (no make_shared, no stack allocations, etc.). I still wonder why constructors stack isn't unroll from base to derived.

Comment: @Piotrek: Well, you can use the special most derived class thing. Enforcing that can be done by using friendship of a virtual top level base, but that has a little bit of overhead. The nice thing about that approach is that there's no way to go wrong for client code.

Comment: @Piotrek: I added an example.

Comment: Yeah, C++ is exceptional beast. I will rather stay with factory ;)